# AutoWireViewModel Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I am learning Prism 6.0.0 and I have problem with AutoWireViewModel Exception. 
I have no idea how IRegionRepository is injected if I don't have any binding to this interface.

Additionaly I am using Ninject and Entity Framework

Whole projest is here: https://github.com/PiotrKowalski93/PrismDemo

I am learning from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY , his code is working fine, but he is using Prism 5.7.0

What I want is to show my EmployeesView after pressing the button.

My Container in MainWindow.xaml

```
 <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
```

Exception is thrown during startup of the application:

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

My Bootstraper.cs

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<EmployeesView>("Employee");            
    }        
}
```

My App.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
        bs.Run();
    }
}
```

My MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }

public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
   _regionManager = regionManager;

    NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
}

private void Navigate(string obj)
{
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", obj);
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What does your ViewModel constructor look like? I would imagine that the constructor's dependencies cannot be resolved automatically.

Comment: I edited my question.  I done it manually but the regions are empty

Comment: Have a look at the inner exception; you are using Unity, not Ninject (as far as I can tell).
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed... Resolving parameter "regionManager"

Comment: You can register it manually (although I have never had to before?):
`Container.RegisterType<IRegionManager, RegionManager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());`

Comment: Yes, look at https://github.com/brianlagunas/InfragisticsWebinarSimpleMVVMPrism/tree/master/PrismDemo/Views

He does not have to register it, and it is working somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so managed to figure it out:

1. I deleted Ninject and I was using only Unity as my main container.
2. I had chaos in my liblaries. I deleted all

   Microsoft.Practices.Prism

   Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MVVM

dll's.

3.I reinstalled Prism package, propably my Prism.WPF and Prism.Unity was on version 6.x.x but my Prism package was on 5.x.x.

Ovecourse I had to move my Interface to Class mapping form Ninject module to Container Configuration in Unity module.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wrote in my edit :-) You had a different IRegionManager interface as your view model's dependency than was registered in the bootstrapper.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [supported IoC containers](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/README.md) for Prism WPF, you see that we have support for Ninject. For this to work you have use the Prism.Ninject package instead of Prism.Unity.

[image: Packages]

The next logic step is replacing the `UnityBootstrapper` base class by the [`NinjectBootstrapper`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Ninject.Wpf/NinjectBootstrapper.cs) class. I'm not familiar with Ninject, so I'm not sure if you'll have to register all types or if Ninject has a way to auto-resolve unregistered types.

Another solution is to replace your Ninject by Unity to be closer to the sample, but this is not part of the question :). There's official support for Ninject, so nothing keeps you from picking your familiar IoC container.

Extra note: *The reason why some things work and others don't is because some IoC containers (like Unity) can resolve instances of concrete types without configuration, while others (like Autofac) allow this with some extra configuration (`AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` in case of Autofac).*

Comment: Thank you, but this was not very helpful. The question is why it doesnt work. Unity should autoresolve my IRegionManager the same way it does it in example (version 5.x).

Answer (score 0):

You should be registering your services with your bootstrapper's Unity Container, not a Ninject Kernel that's never used for resolution. Unity doesn't know that `IHrService` should be resolved to `HrService`... try adding

```
Container.RegisterType<IHrService, HrService>();
```

to your bootstrapper's `ConfigureContainer`.

EDIT: Additionally, be sure to resolve the correct `IRegionManager`, that is `Prism.Regions.IRegionManager` from Prism 6. Your solution contains a lot of references to older Prism components, and your usings include stuff from those (like `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionManager`...)

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that I am using Unity For Prism to resolve VIew/VIewModels. Additionaly I have ninject to inject dependencjes for my VIewModels like Services. Error is thrown from ViewModelLocator. It cnat resolve IRegionManager which is in MainWindowViewModel. I didnt register it but on the tutorial which I gave it is workin. Somehow it is autoresolved. Check it here: https://github.com/brianlagunas/InfragisticsWebinarSimpleMVVMPrism/tree/master/PrismDemo

Comment: It registers the region manager in `UnityBootstrapper.ConfigureContainer`, and you call that, so it should be fine.